# How to do arithmetic with variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a web app, obviously for this I would need to know how to modify variables. I'm new to JS, is there something I'm missing? The following returns NaN

```
        var example = 30
    function add() {
        var example = example + 10
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = example
    }

    <P id="text"></text>
<button onclick="add()">
```

Comment: You redeclared the variable `example`. p.s. there's no such thing called: `</text>` (typo?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't re-declared the same variable example, And you have to complete properly close the button tag and paragraph tag

You will need these changes

```js
var example = 30
function add() 
{
  example = example + 10
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = example
}
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
<button onclick="add()">submit</button>
```

Comment: Did you see any of the answer's in SO which starts with like "Hello, Joshua Riefman" and ends with "This would work 100 %"?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't redeclare the `example` variable inside the function again if you want to use the value assigned outside

```js
 var example = 30
function add() {
    example = example + 10
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = example
}
```

```html
<P id="text"></p>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring the variable in the function - also you can abbreviate is as follows:  `example += 10;` which is he quvalent of saying example is the value of example plus 10.

```js
var example = 30
    
    function add() {
        example += 10;
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = example
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Click Me</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have re-declared the same variable, that's why on a function-scope view, `example` is NaN.

```js
var example = 30
 function add() {
    example += 10;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = example
 }
```